# Как из телеграм чата переносить данные в таблицу excel

Tags: python, excel, telegram

Я совсем новичек, хочу попробовать написать модуль, обратотку. Может кто подскажет с чего начать и направит. Необходимо получать данных из чата и занесить их в таблицу excel. Данные с определенными условиями! Обработка которая будет брать из телеграм- чата каждую новую запись, проверять на соответствие условиям, и заносить с таблицу. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы захватывать данные из чата, можно использоваться [Telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/)

Читайте документацию, там довольно все просто написано.

Далее прикручиваете уже обработчик exel по условиям которые вам нужны